# How to "subtract 1" from a flags-type enum?

Tags: c#, enums, .net-2.0

I have an `enum` defined as such:

```
[Flags]
public enum NodeLevel
{
    Root = 1,
    GroupLevel = 2,
    DeptLevel = 4,
    ClassLevel = 8,
    SubclassLevel = 16
}
```

I've defined it as `Flags` so that I can perform bitwise operations on them. Now I need to be able to "subtract 1" from the level so that given a specific level I can retrieve the next level up. For example, an object contains a value of `NodeLevel.ClassLevel` and I need to send `NodeLevel.DeptLevel` to a method.

Since `NodeLevel newLevel = currentLevel - 1;` doesn't work, does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can accomplish this? I imagine it's something absurdly simple but my brain won't come up with it at the moment.

I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Have you tried bitshift?

Comment: @Bob. I did, but I didn't get all the casting right so the compiler wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've only got a single flag, you can just divide by 2, with appropriate casting:

```
NodeLevel newLevel = (NodeLevel) ((int)currentLevel / 2);
```

(Interesting, you can add and subtract without any casting at all... but multiplication, division, shifting etc require casting both ways.)

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. I tried something similar but couldn't get all the casting right so it wasn't allowed. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why multiplication and division require casting but addition and subtraction do not?

Comment: @SidHolland: Nope - it's just the way the language is specified... (7.8.5 of the C# 5 spec gives subtraction, for example - that talks about enums, but the section on division doesn't.)

Comment: @SidHolland OK, in this case it looks like there are only five "flags", so negative values is never an issue. With non-negative `x` of integral type, the expressions `x/2` and `x>>1` always produce the same result. For negative odd `x` there's a difference, but both `x/2` and `x>>1` are probably "wrong" (give another result than desired) in this case. So therefore you could consider casting to `uint` instead of `int`. You could also make `uint` the underlying type of your enum to signal that you want these operations.

Answer (score 6):

You can use right shift operator too.

```
NodeLevel newLevel = (NodeLevel) ((int)currentLevel >> 1)
```